# How can I set the AppData folder for a new process?

Tags: c#, process, environment-variables

I would like to start a new process but I need it to use a different folder for `AppData`. In a windows batch file you can do it like this:

`set APPDATA=C:\MyDataFolder`

It will set the `AppData` for any program launched in the batch file, so how can I do this in C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [add environment variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.environmentvariables.aspx) to the `ProcessStartInfo`:

```
ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo("some_executable.exe");
p.UseShellExecute = false; // apparently required when adding environment variables
p.EnvironmentVariables.Add("APPDATA", @"C:\MyDataFolder");
Process.Start(p);
```

Comment: @t27o: `p` is a `ProcessStartInfo` object which contains these properties directly. Are you confusing it with the `Process` class?

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head: [Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z46c489x%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

According to MSDN:

> Creates, modifies, or deletes an environment variable stored in the
>   current process.

Current process being the operative word...